# how to add xml to wordpress site without FTP access

Tags: xml, wordpress

I want to add an xml sitemap to my wordpress site. 
I don't want to use a plugin, I want to use my own file.

I think that I have to save it to the root directory, but I don't know how to do this because I don't have FTP access. How can I get around this?

Thanks!

Comment: WP SEO by Yoast generates its own sitemap

Answer (score 0):

You can generate sitemap without plugin.
Have you tried this:
http://emrahgunduz.com/categories/development/wordpress/create-sitemap-xml-in-wordpress-without-any-plugins/
http://electnewmedia.com/wordpress-sitemap-page/
http://bacsoftwareconsulting.com/blog/index.php/wordpress-cat/how-to-add-dynamic-html-sitemap-in-wordpress-without-plugin/
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/15218/how-to-generate-update-a-xml-sitemap-without-plugins
There are more examples in the web.